# Delphi Rem Objects Pascal compile in Linux 64

Tags: linux, delphi, pascal

Did anyone manage to build Rem Objects Pascal Script for Linux 64? Currently Linux Platform seems only to be supported for FPC. That and the fact that it compiled with Kylix long ago leads me to the assumption that it should also be possible to compile it in the modern Delphi 10.4 Linux Compiler.

Out of the box the build fails in the assembler parts and many other areas using the current GitHub code.

I am only talking about the core of compiling and executing scripts, perhaps adding database stuff and no GUI functionality.

Please note: I am not asking for "please do the work for me"! I just would be grateful if anyone has managed getting it up and running with Delphi 10.4 Linux and would share his experiences and tips.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that current Linux support in Delphi does not rely on the old Kylix code. This means that there is no guarantee that the code that compiled just fine with Kylix will even compile in modern Delphi

Comment: I am aware of the differences between old Kylix and the current compiler. I meant the fact that it can be compiled for Linux at least shows that there is no fundamental dependency on Windows.

Comment: Pascalscript per target support is mostly ABI and calling conventions which are totally different for 64-bit, so Kylix wouldn't help at all. Different target and 20 years of attrition(which is a long time on Linux). Therefore getting the FPC 64-bitoption to work with Delphi would be easier, but release versions of FPC use SJ exception handling and Delphi might use EH_FRAME.

Comment: Thanks, so there is very little chance and I will try to find a different scripting engine like TMS Scripter.

Comment: I don't find this question unclear. On the contrary, there are proof of personal research and understanding.

Comment: To answer the question: there is no support yet of RemObjects PS for Delphi Linux x64. The assembly parts wont compile, but for minor issues, which are easy to fix, like `.noframe` for Delphi instead of `nostackframe;` for FPC. The assembly itself could remain the same, since the ABI is the same. Take a look at https://github.com/synopse/mORMot2/blob/master/src/core/mormot.core.interfaces.pas for some Delphi/FPC Linux x64 ASM stubs executing functions.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I will give it an other try.